# Generic Method Executed with a runtime type

Tags: c#, generics, methods

I have the following code:

```
 public class ClassExample
{

    void DoSomthing<T>(string name, T value)
    {
        SendToDatabase(name, value);
    }

    public class ParameterType
    {
        public readonly string Name;
        public readonly Type DisplayType;
        public readonly string Value;

        public ParameterType(string name, Type type, string value)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
                throw new ArgumentNullException("name");
            if (type == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("type");

            this.Name = name;
            this.DisplayType = type;
            this.Value = value;
        }
    }

    public void GetTypes()
    {
        List<ParameterType> l = report.GetParameterTypes();

        foreach (ParameterType p in l)
        {
            DoSomthing<p.DisplayType>(p.Name, (p.DisplayType)p.Value);
        }

    }
}
```

Now, I know I cannot perform DoSomething()
is there any other way to use this function?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You can, but it involves reflection, but you can do it.

```
typeof(ClassExample)
    .GetMethod("DoSomething")
    .MakeGenericMethod(p.DisplayType)
    .Invoke(this, new object[] { p.Name, p.Value });
```

This will look at the top of the containing class, get the method info, create a generic method  with the appropriate type, then you can call Invoke on it.

Comment: Just one catch, p.Value is a string so the invoke will fail unless p.DisplayType happens to be typeof(string).

Comment: shame this is the only solution, meh

Comment: Well, I'm thinking that you can use dynamic in 4.0 and it will infer the correct generic argument type, but I haven't had a chance to verify it yet. Not that it is doing anything different under the covers than the above code, but maybe it is.

Answer (score 5):

```
this.GetType().GetMethod("DoSomething").MakeGenericMethod(p.Value.GetType()).Invoke(this, new object[]{p.Name, p.Value});
```

Should work.

Comment: About brevity: _Can_ does not imply _should_.

Answer (score 3):

Generics types cannot be specified at runtime the way you'd like to here.

The simplest options would be to add a non-generic overload of `DoSomething`, or simply call `DoSomething<object>` and ignore `p.DisplayType`.  Unless `SendToDatabase` depends on the *compile-time* type of `value` (and it probably shouldn't), there should be nothing wrong with giving it an `object`.

If you can't do those, you'll have to call `DoSomething` using reflection, and you'll take a big performance hit.

Answer (score 3):

First we need to convert `p.Value` to the right type, since even if we know the type at compile time we can't pass the string straight to the method...

```
DoSomething<Int32>( "10" ); // Build error
```

For simple numeric types and DateTime, we can use

```
object convertedValue = Convert.ChangeType(p.Value, p.DisplayType);
```

Now we can use reflection to invoke the required generic method...

```
typeof(ClassExample)
    .GetMethod("DoSomething")
    .MakeGenericMethod(p.DisplayType)
    .Invoke(this, new object[] { p.Name, convertedValue });
```

Answer (score 1):

Strictly saying you can use [MethodInfo.MakeGenericMethod](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodinfo.makegenericmethod.aspx) for this.

But I recommend to change DoSomething to non-generic form instead, since it is not evident whether it really should be generic.

Comment: I just simplified the program for the explanation. This is actually the most elegant solution, believe it or not. :) thanks!