# Call generic method which T is a Type

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

there is a generic method which selects a field from an entity as below

```
public object GetOrderDynamically<T>(Expression selectPredicate, Expression predicate, Type type)
    {
        var order = orderFacade.FetchMulti((Expression<Func<Order, bool>>) predicate).AsQueryable();
        return order.Select((Expression<Func<Order, T>>)selectPredicate).FirstOrDefault();

    }
```

Search result for calling the method was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1606966/generic-method-executed-with-a-runtime-type)

the problem : I want to clarify type of the selected field . but this method is located in business layer and I can use it with its interface . actually business layers classes would be injectd into my class with IoC .

Somehow I want to call my methods with reflection which are instantiated by injection and be able to set T as a Type

Any help . thanks

Comment: It isn't clear what you want to obtain... Try writing how you call the method and how you would like to call the method.

Comment: Are you asking how to call generic methods via reflection? It is a little unclear to me at present...

Comment: I want to call it like this                 var tt = typeof(Datetime);                         orderBiz.GetOrderDynamically<tt>(selectExp, predicateExp);

Comment: It is simply not a good idea to mix generics and reflection. If the method takes a `Type`, it shouldn't also have a `<T>` that means the same thing - and calling it via reflection isn't going to capitalise on the `<T>`. You might as well just return `object` and forget the `<T>` completely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use the **MakeGenericMethod** method that is available on MethodInfo, e.g

```
    someTarget.GetType()
        .GetMethod("SomeGenericMethod")
        .MakeGenericMethod(typeof(SomeGenericArgument)
        .Invoke(someTarget, someParameters);
```

See also:

[Calling generic method with a type argument known only at execution time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/325156/calling-generic-method-with-a-type-argument-known-only-at-execution-time)

**EDIT - For given example**

> orderBiz.GetOrderDynamically<tt>(selectExp, predicateExp); –  unos
>   baghaii 5 mins ago

```
    orderBiz.GetType().GetMethod("GetOrderDynamically").MakeGenericMethod(tt).Invoke(orderBiz, new object [] { selectExp, predicateExp });
```

Comment: But I want to call my instance's method which I do not know how to call.

Comment: someTarget is your instance.