# How to call method with generic type parameter dynamically

Tags: c#, generics

I have code like this.

```
var sampleBus = BusConfigurator.Instance
                .ConfigureBus((cfg, host) =>
                {
                    cfg.ReceiveEndpoint(host, "sampleQueue", e =>
                    {
                        e.UseScheduledRedelivery(r => r.Intervals(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));
                        e.UseMessageRetry(r => r.Interval(5, 5000));
                        e.Consumer<ConsumerClass1>();
                    });
                });

sampleBus.Start();
```

I have a lot of consumer classes and i want to handle this with config file.How can i convert class names in config file to ConsumerClasses.

```
foreach(string className in consumerClassNameList){ 

????

var sampleBus = BusConfigurator.Instance
                    .ConfigureBus((cfg, host) =>
                    {
                        cfg.ReceiveEndpoint(host, "sampleQueue", e =>
                        {
                            e.UseScheduledRedelivery(r => r.Intervals(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));
                            e.UseMessageRetry(r => r.Interval(5, 5000));
                            e.Consumer<???>();
                        });
                    });

sampleBus.Start();
}
```

Each ConsumerClass derive from :

```
public class ConsumerClass1<T> : IConsumer<T> where T : class
```

Appraciate for any help.

**EDIT**

I asked question wrong.This code,

```
e.Consumer<ConsumerClass1>();
```

is not initialize a class.It is invoking a method.

```
public static void Consumer<TConsumer>(this IReceiveEndpointConfigurator configurator, Action<IConsumerConfigurator<TConsumer>> configure = null) where TConsumer : class, IConsumer, new();
```

Sorry for wrong question.Question should be "how to call method with generic type parameter dynamically". I found answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1606966/generic-method-executed-with-a-runtime-type).

Comment: I don't understand your question, can you explain better?

Answer (score 0):

To add to Johnny's answer: you can obtain `Type` object via `Type.GetType(string)`:

```
> Type.GetType(typeof(int).AssemblyQualifiedName)
[System.Int32]
```

You should provide assembly-qualified name, which can be obtained via corresponding property of `Type` object. Type should be present in any of imported namespaces.