# Configure MassTransit Message at runtime

Tags: c#, masstransit

I would like the configure MassTransit `Message` at runtime. I could not find a way to do this and was wondering if I missed something or if it is not possible. Here is what it currently looks like:

```cs
var azureServiceBus = Bus.Factory.CreateUsingAzureServiceBus(busConfig =>
{
    busConfig.Message<MyType>(configTopology =>
    {
        // Do some configuration
    });
});
```

This is what I would like to do though:

```cs
var azureServiceBus = Bus.Factory.CreateUsingAzureServiceBus(busConfig =>
{
    foreach (var myType in myTypes)
    {
        busConfig.Message(myType, configTopology =>
        {
            // Do some configuration
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no overloads from Message that accept a `Type` argument, the types must be specified as a generic type argument. You could, however, use an approach to call a generic method at runtime specifying a type argument as seen in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1606966/generic-method-executed-with-a-runtime-type/1606988#1606988).

Comment: I ended up creating a private method in the wrapper class which calls all the methods from the bus so there is only one part which is dynamically calling a generic method. It worked out really well!